# Mechanize can't find right fields

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to login into the following site: https://login.binck.nl/klanten/

Mechanize can only find the field `__RequestVerificationToken` but not the `username` and `password` field. I used this code to discover the fields:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('https://login.binck.nl/klanten/')
form = page.forms.first
form.fields.each { |f| puts "#{f.name} : #{f.value}" }
```

It seems the `username` and `password` fields don't have a name and the website is using Knockout.js, so probably that's the reason it's not working. Even by adding the `username` and `password` fields the website still doesn't let me sign in

```
form.add_field!('username', 'MY_USERNAME')
form.add_field!('password', 'MY_PASSWORD')

page = agent.submit form

puts page.body
```

Does anybody have the solution how I can automate the login on this website?

Comment: Binck.nl is a banking site. It probably has some security restrictions in place to prevent bots/scripts from logging in.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an attempt to answer the question asked, but it'll help you figure out how to deal with the problem. This is a general process you'd use for any scraping or form-stuffing automation, and only the selector used to find particular nodes changes usually.

1. Use [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) to retrieve the actual HTML for the page; Retrieve the HTML and dump it to a file so you can see *exactly* what is sent, without a browser or any other code messing with it:

   ```
   require 'open-uri'

   File.write('test.html', open('https://login.binck.nl/klanten/').read)
   ```

   If the fields you want are not in the form when retrieved by OpenURI, then neither Nokogiri or Mechanize can help you, since Mechanize is built on top of Nokogiri, which it uses for its parsing. In this case, they *ARE* in the HTML, so Nokogiri, and Mechanize, can find them, you just need to know how to do it:

   ```
   <input data-bind="value: $root.username, setFocus:true" type="password"/>
   <input data-bind="value: $root.password" type="password"/>
   ```
2. In Nokogiri you can find a particular node multiple different ways. It supports CSS and XPath selectors which let you look inside a node's attributes/parameters. Sometimes the node doesn't have anything that's particularly distinguishing, so you look *around* it for landmarks. In this case the `class="form_line"` in the surrounding `<div>` tags is your basis for a search, and for added definition, we can add the surrounding `<div class="body">`. Alternately, the `<input>` tags are also useful because we can look at the `type` parameter. Here's a CSS selector that will pick up the "password" input tags in that block:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'
   require 'open-uri'

   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://login.binck.nl/klanten/'))
   inputs = doc.css('input[@type="password"]')
   ```

   If I run that code in IRB I can look at the nodes returned:

   ```
   >> puts doc.css('input[@type="password"]').map(&:to_html)
   ```

   And see:

   ```
   <input data-bind="value: $root.username, setFocus:true" type="password">
   <input data-bind="value: $root.password" type="password">
   ```

So, the fields exist. The above shows you how to point to them using Nokogiri, which is core to Mechanize. Mechanize exposes the parsed Nokogiri DOM to you. How you do that and use it is left as an exercise for you.

The input tags don't have, or need, `name` parameters, because the page is using [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to process the fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/klanten/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js" ></script>
```

(Play with the tutorials for it, especially from page "3 of 5" on, to see what it's doing in the page you're trying to parse.)

Here's where the above stuff starts to fall apart...

Mechanize can't stuff values into the fields and submit them, because Knockout has to do its part, which takes a JavaScript interpreter. You're going to have to try using a WATIR-driven browser to allow it to process the JavaScript, which will let Knockout run, so it can then do it's magic and submit the data. (If it wasn't a HTTPS connection you could sniff the wire using [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to find the values being sent but that'd only be part of the solution, and you'd have to also be capturing cookies and session info.)

Taking apart JavaScript makes the task more difficult too, because it can be so dynamic. Code can be loaded as the page loads, or behind the scenes well after the page has loaded, based on some trigger occurring, such as the Submit button being clicked, so the code won't be visible at all. You'd have to sniff the wire or spend time disassembling their code. Either way, the job gets a lot harder.

The problem with sniffing the connection is, HTTPS wraps the normal HTTP traffic from the browser to server inside a [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) layer to protect it from prying eyes. As a result, normal tools, like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and [TCPDump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) can't really help as they're not SSL-saavy. [ssldump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/Ssldump.html) might get you where you need to be, depending on your OS.

In his answer, @pguardiario says to use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to get inside the HTTPS/SSL layer to see the actual data being passed back and forth. Those will let you see the field-names after Knockout and the SSL layer have had their chance to play with things. Perhaps he'll expand on his answer to help you more.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using open-uri to answer a mechanize question.

Comment: Because it's a waste of time using Mechanize to retrieve the HTML just to dump it to disk to confirm the tags were static. Did you read what I wrote? This was to help the OP learn how to figure out whether Nokogiri or Mechanize was an appropriate tool.

Comment: No, we already know that mechanize is an appropriate tool. Open-uri is the waste of time because it's a dead end. You're also wrong about the input tags, they don't have names so they're not form fields.

Comment: Wireshark can't 'sniff' https traffic. You need a mitm proxy for that. You often come up with insightful posts, but this answer is really a complete loss. There's nothing helpful here, just a lot of pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: You're right, it's a HTTPs connection, and Wireshark can't help as the SSL pipe hides what's on the wire. It would be useful for a normal unencrypted HTTP connection. Again, this answer was to get the user thinking how to deal with this stuff. You might have a different direction; You're entitled to it. The OP is the one needing the help and you seem to have lost sight of that; Explain how you'd do it in more detail, and help instead of attack other answers.

Comment: The problem is that you see a downvote as an attack. I downvoted because it's a bad answer. It cannot possibly help anyone :(

Comment: In other words, we're building a knowledge base here, not fighting a war. If you realize that your contribution is to the detriment of that, you should remove it. And I think you do.

Answer (score 1):

In general you would do:

```
form['username'] = 'foo'
form['password'] = 'bar'
```

However, these are not the right field names. To discover the right field names you want to proxy your browser request through a ssl (mitm) proxy like fiddler or charles and see what it's sending.

It looks like you'll need to change `form.method` too.